# 500 error keeps springing up once a day

Tags: apache2

I have a strange issue on my digital ocean droplet running Ubuntu, all i did was install a wordpress installation (i have since removed it) the issue is, every day at some point it springs up a "500" error, to fix it i have to do a reboot, once it reboots it works fine, then at some point during the day it reverts back to a "500" error, then i need to reboot again to fix it, it has been every day for a few days now, i don't see any errors in the **/var/log/apache2** log, i'm not sure what else to check, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Webserver errors should go into `error.log` and as wordpress is PHP based you should have a `php_error.log`.

If unsure grep for error in /var/log `grep -rli error /var/log/*` to find all logs with error messages and identify the ones concerning the apache websever and your wordpress engine.

When you say you reboot, I take it you mean you reboot your droplet, or just the apache daemon?

HTTP status code 500 flags internal server errors, indicating, that the webengine, in this case your wordpress, has problems; mostly this stems from backend problems: Databse connect, system ressources like filled up partitions.

Next time this happens, before you reboot take a short look at the system:

- `df -h` to find filled partions
- `free` to check on your memory
- `sudo less /var/log/messages` to check for any system errors
- `sar` and `sar -r` to check system activity